# Why will a full gc on small heap takes 5 seconds?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, garbage-collection

I am running an J2EE application on 3 year old Solaris system with a used heap that is about 300 MB. From the gc logs I have seen that the full gc that is triggered a few times a day takes about 5 seconds and recovers about 200 MB every time. What could be the reason for a full gc to take such a long time on such a small heap?

I run java 1.6.0_37.

Comment: It really depends on the amount of objects stored on the heap.

Comment: Is the code creating and deleting many objects? Does this happen for many/all programs?>

Comment: Interesting. So the amount of objects is the important factor here, not the size? If yes, how can I see how many objects I create?

Comment: you can stop the compaction as by default gc performs partial heap memory compaction. compaction may lead to increase in gc time.

Answer (score 3):

A slow full GC (and minor GC for that matter) is primary a result of a poor hardware setup and secondly software configuration (i.e. GC ergonomics), and at last the number of object residing in the heap.

Looking at the hardware, what CPU model and vendor are you using on your Solaris? Is it a SMP system with more than one core. Do you have more than one thread per core? Do your GC utilize all available virtual processors on the system i.e. is the garbage collection distributed across more than one processor?

Another situation making full GC to perform slow is if a part of the heap is swapped out from main memory. In that case the memory pages swapped out must be swapped in during the garbage collection which can be a rather time consuming process. In that case you do not have sufficient physical memory installed on the machine.

Does any other applications on the system compete for the same physical resources, i.e. CPU and memory?

Looking at the GC ergonomics, what collector are you using? I would recommend the parallel throughput collector or the G1 collector using multiple collector threads. I would also recommend to use a NUMA configuration.

Some general rules:

- The better hardware and GC ergonomics, the faster the individual garbage collections will perform.
- The fewer and smaller objects the application creates, the less often will the garbage collector run.
- The fewer long lived object created, the less often will the full garbage collector run.

For more information about GC ergonomics:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think I can blame the server. Its unused except for my application and I have several cores and two threads per core and lots of free memory available. Looking at vmstat the system has very low load. How can I see how many objects I create? I can see how much heap I use in the gc logs but I don't know were to see how many objects I create. (I get back to you regarding the collector ASAP)

Comment: I have experience from Solaris and multicore Sparc processors not performing very well when it comes to garbage collection. Although you have a SMP system with no load and utilizing all available cores/strands/threads the CPU can be a bad performer.

Comment: I am sure that is true, but both you and the comments above says that creating lots of object can make the gc slow and neither answers how I can measure that. Do you have any good suggestion ? Thanks again for your response.

Comment: I think that it is only possible with instrumentation of the garbage collector itself. But what you can do is a test where you create fewer and larger objects to be garbage collected and compare it with the current situation and see how the number of objects freed affect the GC delay.

Comment: Btw. in our system we have rather big heaps, >20Gb with a huge amount of objects freed every GC cycle. Each full GC cycle will take approx. 3 seconds to perform.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Impressive heap...By the way operations have answered and they have set -XX:+UseParallelGC as the gc and well, that is not a good idea. One thread for a full gc if I remember correctly. Changing it to UseParallelOldGC would probably make a difference.

Comment: The UseParallelGC and UseParallelOldGC can be combined. This means that both the young generation and the old generation will be collected by parallel threads.
-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -Xloggc:gc.log
You can use the-XX:ParallelGCThreads=X to control the number of parallel GC threads, if not set the number of available processors will be utilized.

Comment: My understanding is that UseParallelOldGC automatically sets -XX:+UseParallelGC but its clearer to put it there. I think I will also have:  -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC also. I have never heard of UseNUMA. I have to look it up. Thanks for your answers!