# Will A java run task scheduled with scheduleWithFixedDelay be stopped during Stop-The-World GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, schedule

I want to implement a heartbeat mechanism in which the child process will periodically ping the parent to tell parent it is still alive. I implement the ping task with threadPool's scheduleWithFixedDelay method in this way:

```
   pingService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new PingGroomServer(umbilical,
          taskId), 0, pingPeriod, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

umbilical is the RPC client to parent process?

Can scheduleWithFixedDelay be scheduled with the fixed delay? Will the ping thread be stopped during Stop-The-World GC?
Actually, I still miss the heartbeat even after I wait for 6 * pingPeriod ms.

Comment: Yes, Stop-The-World-GC does "stop the world". Even without it, I think these timers are not completely guaranteed to fire exactly on time (just not before time).

Comment: poor question.  Not enough detail.  Do you miss all heartbeats or some times?  Did you run with -verbose:gc and some logging and was the correlation between missed pings and gc?

Answer (score 3):

So there are several choices for a more deterministic runtime (Gc pauses, thread sheduling etc) in your application

1. Go predicable, go realtime. One way is to heading for a realtime Java implementation based on RTSJ or other realtime Java implementations like: 
   http://fiji-systems.com/
   http://www.aicas.com/
   http://www-03.ibm.com/linux/realtime.html
2. Go low latency, go no stop-the-world GC. One other way is to use Java implementations with no stop-the-world Garbage collection pauses, like the Zing JVM from Azul systems which uses a low latency concurrent collector.
   http://www.azulsystems.com/solutions/low-latency/overview

Since the above choices may is a rather big step for a small application there are things you can do with a "classic" Java implementation.

So, if you want short GC pauses with a Oracle/OpenJDK JVM there are some rule of thumbs:

- Hardware - This is the most important. You must have a SMP system with a fast multi-threaded CPU and fast memory modules. Avoid swapping. So the faster hardware you have, the faster the Garbage collector will perform.
- Use a multithreaded garbage collector. If you are using the Oracle JVM go for G1 or parallelGC (aka throughput collector)
- Use a small heap, the larger heap the more space must be handled by the Garbage collector.
- Tune memory (heap) ergonomics. Fine tune your memory ergonomics, let the objects be collected in the young generation (and not be promoted to the old generation) to avoid Full garbage collections.

Another answer to a similar question:
[Why will a full gc on small heap takes 5 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399962/why-will-a-full-gc-on-small-heap-takes-5-seconds/18400792#18400792)

For more information about GC ergonomics: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, stop-the-world is exactly what it says it is - every thread that accesses objects on the heap that is not specifically involved with the garbage collector is stopped.

If you want a heartbeat in java, best to farm out to a separate VM running just that code so the VM pauses are not so long. Or better still, not rely upon millisecond timing - you can't assume that level of scheduling amongst processes in desktop OSs.